# Magento 2 Admin : How to increase number of products shown under related products in admin section?

Tags: magento2, admin, pagination, related-products

I want to sort the product by grag and drop , but both product are in different page , So want to remove pagination or show 100 products instead of 20 , Any Suggestion would be appreciated !

Comment: Check the answer for same solution.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/294869/how-to-remove-pagination-from-customizable-options-backend-in-magento-2/294901#294901

Comment: Thanks , but it didnt work for me ! Any other solution(s) ?

Comment: what the error are you facing ?

Comment: There isn't any error , just doesn't work . I want to show more products in product under related products.

Comment: Same posted solution working for me. can you check the module JS file is called or not ?

Comment: As far as i can see in source view , it donsnt look like it has been called any file like module js file

Comment: It worked now ! been in wrong place ! Thanks a lot !